# menuPortalTarget not working properly in AsyncSelect

Tags: reactjs, react-select

```
       <AsyncSelect
          classes={classes}
          key={this.props.index}
          inputId={"react-select-input-" + uniqueInput}
          defaultOptions={
            this.props.defaultOptions ? this.props.defaultOptions : []
          }
          isClearable
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          loadOptions={(value, callback) => {
            if (this.props.index >= 0) {
              this.props.handleInputChange(
                value,
                this.props.index,
                callback
              );
            } else {
              this.props.handleInputChange(value, callback);
            }
          }}
          components={this.components}
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChangeSingle}
          styles={
            this.props.isInPopup
              ? { menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }
              : {}
          }
          menuPortalTarget={this.props.isInPopup ? document.body : false}
        />
```

Adding any new input - causes the dropdown to appear at the bottom of the screen
[image]
And when I hover over the drowpdown at the bottom, it places it back to the right spot below the Select Input. Don't know why it happens. Any help here would be great.

I think it has something to do with menuPortalTarget but I dont know how to set it correctly in this case.

The first load default values work fine but Async callback based updated menu moves at the bottom of screen.
Below is the Menu after hovering/First Default value load. Which is what should happen always
[image]